# How to get absolute signal in PyAudio?

Tags: audio, portaudio, pyaudio

I'm trying to use pyaudio to analyze audio playing on my computer's system. To do this I am selecting a recording device called Stereo Mix as my input signal into pyaudio. Stereo Mix seems to be a recording device provided by my computer's soundcard, VIA High Definition Audio.

The problem is the signal I get from pyaudio changes in amplitude when I increase the volume on my computer. I would like to get an absolute signal which does not change with increased volume (ideally the raw signal generated from the computer's system). Does anyone have a solution this problem?

Thanks

Comment: In general, audio goes through the mixer before it gets to your application. Could could check if your OS supports "raw" channels.